# Is there an explanation for why properties accessed on a generic types are not indexed access by default

Tags: typescript

I would like to understand why given an object type for example

```
type Obj = {
  readonly color: string;
};
```

and a function to get its color

```
  const getColor = <const T extends Obj>(obj: T) => obj.color;
  getColor({color:"blue"});
```

The type of `obj.color` is `string` rather than `T["color"]` by default. To get the actual value we have to explicitly type the return.

```
  const getColor = <const T extends Obj>(obj: T):T['color'] => obj.color;
```

But if we had some more general function to get the value of any property given its key:

```
  const getPropertyValue = <const T extends Obj, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key:K) => obj[key];
```

Then the type of `obj[key]` is `T[K]`.

So I guess it's not a type safety issue, or that typescript can't figure out the type.
So I would like to know if there's a reason for this, and if there is some way, other than explicitly typing the return, to get the return as indexed access.

This works but maybe unnecessary.

```
  const getPropertyValue = <const T extends Obj, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key:K) => obj[key];
  const getColor = <const T extends Obj>(obj:T)=>getPropertyValue(obj,"color")
  const c1 = getColor({color:"blue"}); //returns blue
```

I can figure out that it's probably not a generic issue because without accessing properties and just returning the value the type is not widened.

Here's a link to a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigZ2MglgOwHMBuAKFNEigHkAjAK3SgG9SopkIBDAEznwQgoAY0QoAXLDHIyAXzKlR%20bFDgNJdRhmYjpkgES0EAVwj6o88kpVr68JKgy2AdKIfEoAek-Y8RVQDWXEJcmKoMULhhmuSs7NbAug5MADwAKlAQAB7AEPg8YfYoAHwAFG4SUGkAlOjFSSge3jwQAGZcxgiJnMDGyPhVbA3IpYYmZtVNnj19ylBGplBD3pyEXMg8CBCYYXCtusqJGShQ%20HDApLLk3rYQwhdxBzYMRY5QKQlVmTl5BTQMZVskhqdXC9Fc0imLXanW6EF6-SwOAIhCGtlepWYFWQ4jGpn0skmXmm8NmYV8KKWV1INwYd0SAHdcMAABbfMAIXDCZkcUn9UiPT7o6SpT4ZbK5fLRAGlIFVariNIAbQA5NiVQBdUEubFkdjChyY7G4hZmQlTGb9MKmqnkGmeW73KBM1lQAIQEJhdaowX8Z70AAKyDgkGQoAAalxxqK-UdvpK-poADRQADS8d%20YXdID2VUB6iqKez4lTtTQ9VsSuzGr1T0SwgAjExbEGQxAwyBI%20MjXo8WaU2rpCqiSs%20XMbZdyEA) with this code.

Comment: That's the way it works, as per  [ms/TS#33181](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194): if you index into a generic object type with a specific key type you well get a specific value type out, not a generic one.  Not sure where to find an authoritative answer for *why*, though; presumably it's for performance/simplicity, but all I can say with certainty is the fact that it is that way.  Does that count or are you really looking for some source for *why* it is that way?  Also, what's wrong with the `T['color']` type annotation to say the type you expect?

Comment: Yea that counts, was just in case there was some obvious reason in terms of consistency or something. Nothing wrong with asserting, in this case its nothing but if accessing 8-9 levels deep you basically write the same thing twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's an *explanation* for it, but for better or worse it is true that indexing into an object of generic type `T extends Constraint` with a key of a *non-generic* type `K` will give you a value of *non-generic* type `Constraint[K]` and not `T[K]`; **the generic type is widened to its constraint before indexing**:

```
function foo<T extends Constraint>(t: T) {
  const val = t.x; // const val: string
}
```

This is mentioned several places in GitHub issues, such as [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194) on [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181), or [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54160#issuecomment-1539681343) from [microsoft/TypeScript#54160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54160).

It doesn't really say *why* this is the case.  Presumably because it's convenient to do so: it keeps the types simple (sometimes *too* simple) which helps with compiler performance.  But that's mostly speculation on my part in lieu of any authoritative explanation.

---

Generally speaking when default TypeScript type heuristic behavior is undesirable, a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) is a reasonable approach:

```
function foo<T extends Constraint>(t: T) {
  const val: T["x"] = t.x; // const val: T["x"]
}
```

Yes, this is redundant, but it works, so it's probably the best you're going to get.  If for some reason you need so many of these that it becomes a problem, you could possibly wrap "generic indexing" as a function and use it:

```
interface Wrap<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(k: K): Wrap<T[K]>;
  val: T
}
const wrap = <T,>(t: T): Wrap<T> => ({
  get(k) { return wrap(t[k]) },
  val: t
})

function foo<T extends Constraint>(t: T) {
  const val = wrap(t).get("x").val // const val: T["x"]
}

interface DeepConstraint {
  a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { f: { g: number } } } } } }
}
function bar<T extends DeepConstraint>(t: T) {
  const val = wrap(t).get("a").get("b").get("c").get("d")
    .get("e").get("f").get("g").val;
  // const val: T["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]["e"]["f"]["g"]
}
```

but that hardly seems worth it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQGcxTqMZAbwChlkAPALmRylAHMAaM5ATxpAFcBbAI2gkAviVEFo8JMgDqeAA4AeACoA+YqwYQwCgNLIIFSCAAmWZAGsIbdDGSqAFOZo6AlDVlxFSgNo6AuioA3KwAbnAANjRKwiQImDjIAO7yyAC8yMpMKvZgUW4y8spqqWr2pOSaYI4uxMhQWlxQIEnyOd7mfjVCLORhkchgwi6iMFwgCGDAmMgw6OjK+oYQJmYY2Lj44Nm5djXlyHHryH1pAwB0FIHIAPTXB-GEfTR0jKyHCX0ATFHeAEQUvz8pzAFyut3uRy+P3+gLeD2OEQAzKdkp4ci4zpV7DCMSdwe9HkjoQC-DESOJYIgUAARCAQORrOibQj7OA0IjIPjsg7c4zciDcmDchicXgCKDIISS6VS2UxUbjSbTPhwKALAxGUzIWn0xkbAjbPLqcgEhHhFGtMAYrG-OC-a1abF8e2Yx2-BAum3GT1uiA+qq-GD+7EMF19YLkfHwp52P52vx-Z0J92Av7e5N+5NB5Oh0kiIA)